# Modify Jquery to expand each photo in different position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been looking a script that expands a photo when mouse is over.

This is the JQuery:

```
this.imagePreview = function(){ 
    /* CONFIG */

        xOffset = 10;
        yOffset = 30;

        // these 2 variable determine popup's distance from the cursor
        // you might want to adjust to get the right result

    /* END CONFIG */
    $("a.preview").hover(function(e){
        this.t = this.title;
        this.title = "";    
        var c = (this.t != "") ? "<br/>" + this.t : "";
        $("body").append("<p id='preview'><img src='"+ this.href +"' alt='Image preview' />"+ c +"</p>");                                
        $("#preview")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
            .fadeIn("fast");                        
    },
    function(){
        this.title = this.t;    
        $("#preview").remove();
    }); 
    $("a.preview").mousemove(function(e){
        $("#preview")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
    });         
};


// starting the script on page load
$(document).ready(function(){
    imagePreview();
});
```

I would like to expand each photo in different absolute position that I want.

To see the demo: http://cssglobe.com/lab/tooltip/02/

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have all previews to occur at the same position, change the coordinates in these lines

```
.css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
.css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
```

Write the coordinate that you want in place of `e.pageY - xOffset` and `e.pageX + yOffset`

Comment: Yes but, this expand all photos in same position, and I want each photo in different position. Thanks!

Comment: Then give each `a` element a different id. And before this, `$("#preview")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
            .fadeIn("fast");` check the id and give position accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("your id").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

clicked anchors will not take the browser to a new URL.